# Is there a way to make VSCode Intellisense suggestions end outside the semicolon?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Intellisense suggestions are handy because I'm lazy, but any time I hit tab/enter to select one, it ends inside the ;. So then I have to arrow right and manually add a new line. Is there a setting or extension that autocompletes to outside the ; and optionally adds new line? or even just complete outside the semicolon. It's kind of cumbersome when writing many CSS rules to have to arrow right in between every line.

Comment: Why not just use the `end` button on your system, and then hit `enter`??

Comment: @brc-dd you don’t really need to. You can create a new line below cursor at any position with CTRL + Enter. I rarely use Enter by itself, even on the end of the line. It’s a good habit to pick up; in my opinion anyways

Comment: @soulshined I hadn't used those hotkeys before. Thanks for letting me know. I think, this pretty much solves OP problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vscodes native way to add a new line anywhere on a line is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can add a new line above at any time using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can try:

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": true,
```

> Controls whether suggestions should be accepted on commit characters. For example, in JavaScript, the semi-colon (`;`) can be a commit character that accepts a suggestion and types that character

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even know that was a feature. Thanks!